# CSS background colour not overriding Datatables styling?

Tags: html, css, datatables

I've implemented a Datatables into my html and all is working fine apart from my css styling? I literally just want to change the background colour and it won't change?

Table code:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class=" row d-flex justify-content-center ">


            <!-- Table: Populate from datatables.js-->
            <table id="movieTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>IMDb</th>
                        <th>Rotten Tomatoes</th>



                    </tr>
                </thead>

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The JS is as below:

```
<script>

    //ajax call to populate datatable from api call
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#movieTable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {

                    //id set to 4 to return Hulu results from api
                    "url": "fake url for security",

                    "dataSrc": "data"
                },
                
                
                "columns": [{

                    //id needed to ensure unique identifier, hidden for better UI design
                        "data": "id",
                        "visible": false
                        
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Title"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Year"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Age"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "IMDb"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Rotten Tomatoes"
                    },

                ],
                
                columnDefs: [
    {
        targets: -1,
        className: 'dt-body-center'
        
        
    }
  ]
  
            });
            
        });

       
    </script>
```

And the css I added was as follows, even added !important to try force it:

```
 #movieTable_wrapper {
        background-color: black !important;
    }
```

Am I missing something massively obvious?

Thanks

Comment: There is [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/) about styling. Did you try to remove the `display` class on the table?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yeah It removed the stripe etc and didn't update the background colour. Once I removed the height from the div its now changing the background colour of the title row only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested i used the inspect on the browser and was able to narrow down to the specific area i wanted to change the colour of. Then i referenced this in the css. Had to be very specific as to what area you wanted to change colour of.

```
table.dataTable,
    table.dataTable th,
    table.dataTable td {
        opacity: 0.85;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the heigth of the wrapping div, and make it display: block, I think it could have no height.

Comment: I removed the min-vh-100 and display block and the background colour has now changed for the title row only?